# Кластеризация текстов после doc2vec

Tags: python, nlp

У меня есть выборка из текстов. Пропустил из через `doc2vec` из библиотеки `gensim`. Результат хороший. Похожие тексты определяет на ура. Как можно кластеризовать тексты?

Пробовал делать так: получил вектор для каждого текста. Закинул все это в `k-means`. Результат получился не очень хороший.

Какие еще подходы можно использовать, имея на руках обученную модель `doc2vec`?

Comment: "Результат получился не очень хороший." - указал бы, что ли - чем именно оказался плох (и на каких данных с какими параметрами). Хотя, вероятно - я не понимаю чего-то вследствие дилетантности :-)  p.s. однако, я - некропостер :-)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `k-means` работает только с расстоянием Евклида, то предлагаю обратить внимание на схожий алгоритм `k-medoids`. Отличается от предыдущего тем, что в последнем можно использовать любое расстояние (в данном случае подойдёт косинусное). Единственный недостаток - `k-medoids` дороже обходится по времени, чем `k-means`.

Полное сравнение алгоритмов предлагается тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619794/what-makes-the-distance-measure-in-k-medoid-better-than-k-means